# PHP tar: create archive with different names

Tags: php, compression, tar, directory-structure, phar

I want to create a `.tar` archive using the PHP Phar extension, containing the original files with changed names:

```
test-dir1
  a
    b.jpg
    c.ogg
  d
    b.png
    c.txt
```

I would like to create archive that look like this:

```
 yet-another-dir
     name-changed-test-dir1
         a
             b.jpg
             c.ogg
         d
             b.png
             c.txt
```

Is it possible without copy the entire directory to a temporary location?

Comment: You can just add files one by one using `$phar["prefixdir/$fn"] = $fn_contents;` or `::addFromString` instead of relying on buildFromDir.

Comment: thanks, that has helped me.